# How to get cities by pollution in OpenAQ Platform API

Tags: javascript, api

I have a problem with Open AQ Platform API documentation https://docs.openaq.org. I have a recruitment task for a Junior place and I have to get 10 cities from specific country and sort them from the most polluted to the less polluted. I can get data for countries that I need but I have no idea how order it by pollution.

At the moment I am using 'https://api.openaq.org/v1/cities' this link with sort-desc parameter cause I assumed that API is using pollution rate as default. But after closer inspection I think that I have to add something to the mix, but I cannot find solution on the website. This is my first contact with API so I am kinda confused how to build the right queries. Underneath you have my code that I manage to wrote at the moment.

```
let country;
let cities = [];
const citiesDiv = document.getElementById("cities");
const countries = ["Poland", "Spain", "Germany", "France"];

const getData = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(
    `https://api.openaq.org/v1/cities?country=${country}&limit=10&sort=desc`
  );
  const data = await response.json();
  cities = data.results;
  citiesDiv.innerHTML = "";
  renderCities(cities);
};

document
  .getElementById("country-picker")
  .addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    if (e.target.value.toLowerCase() === "poland".toLowerCase()) {
      country = "PL";
    } else if (e.target.value.toLowerCase() === "spain".toLowerCase()) {
      country = "ES";
    } else if (e.target.value.toLowerCase() === "germany".toLowerCase()) {
      country = "DE";
    } else if (e.target.value.toLowerCase() === "france".toLowerCase()) {
      country = "FR";
    }

    getData();
  });

function renderCities(cities) {
  cities.forEach(function(city) {
    const p = document.createElement("p");
    p.textContent = city.city;
    citiesDiv.appendChild(p);
  });
}
```

Comment: There's no simple "pollution" metric anyway – you can see the different parameters tracked at https://api.openaq.org/v1/parameters . I think the https://docs.openaq.org/#api-Latest API is more what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was looking for the latest before but it can answer with same city name few times even if 10 is limit. I think that every city have multiple measurement points and this is why. I tried to change parameters and results was different but still don't think that's the right solution. My next step is to take the city name and render a short note from the wikipedia api, and the results in Germany are kinda strange for example 'Rainer Nothard' or 'Heinz Ott'. It is not even a city. I am confused cause some results are city name and some are like that.

Comment: It looks to me like you'll need to take the output of more than one API and combine it then, e.g. cities to find the ten cities that you're interested in and then latest to get the pollution numbers. Then combine that data in your code and sort on what you've got.